# how to Insert data into a database by fetching data from another database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, vb.net, crystal-reports

I have two database for example(A and B). I have already made a crystal report which take values from database 'B'. But now I want to upload this report to the Database 'A' with an unique id. When the user will see the report the program will fetch the report from Database 'A'. And the the report will take the data from database 'B'. Need some suggestions.

Comment: This is not what i meant.

Comment: where is your unique id getting generated? On the front-end (i.e. asp.net side) or sql server side? Also is it getting generated before fetching the record or after fetching the record?

Comment: It is a bit confusing... where do you upload the report and how the unique ID is generated? can you elaborate more

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming that your are calling a stored procedure to fetch data for your report.

In your SP after writing your select statement for your report, you can fire insert queries to databaseA from databaseB itself

If your databases are across different servers and both the servers can talk, you could do in with a SQL insert statement.

first run the following on your first server:

```
Execute sp_addlinkedserver SERVER_NAME1
```

Then just create the insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO [SERVER_NAME1].DATABASE_NAME.dbo.TABLE_NAME   (Names_of_Columns_to_be_inserted)
SELECT Names_of_Columns_to_be_inserted
FROM TABLE_NAME
```

If both the databases are on the same server then you can exclude the [SERVER_NAME1] part from the above query.

If this doesnt solve your query then please elaborate your question.

Hope this helps

Comment: wow.. The answer is marked as accepted and still getting a downvote!! Care to explain why the downvote?

Answer (score 2):

We can copy all columns from one table to another, existing table:

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT * FROM table1;
```

Or we can copy only the columns we want to into another, existing table:

```
INSERT INTO table2
(column_name(s))
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1;
```